# Shower stall leaking water in the corner

Tags: shower, leak, caulk

My master shower is leaking water at the corner. I have tried to fix it myself one month ago. It only worked for 3 weeks then start leaking again. Should I find shower repair company to redo the stall? or should I just recaulk myself? I feel recaulk might not resolve the root issue. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance

highlighted is the leaking area
[image: Leaking area]

I remove the grout which is detached from the stall
[image: place where i fix myself]

This is after I put new grout and I also put sealant on the new grout
[image: redo the grout]

Old grout is detached from the stall.
[image: seam]

Comment: When you say it is "leaking", do you mean to say that you are finding water outside of the shower area? Like on the floor outside, or seeping from the ceiling in a lower storey?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it   Yes, I find water outside of the shower especially near the stall area. If I don't use shower, I never see any water in that area. I test my finding by putting the running water near the stall inside the shower room. I can see the water seeping outside of the stall

Answer (score 1):

In your third picture there is still a small crack right next to the door track. That corner will do a great job of catching water and letting seep down the wall. Caulk is better to use when changing plane. The caulk on the floor is starting to separate.

Comment: do you have any caulk type or brand to recommend? Thank you.

Comment: GE silicone II  is a great caulk. have used it many times with great results